# Jave Swing - Drawing lines by dragging mouse: Why does my code work?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm learning the basics of Swing, and I managed to make this program to draw a line by dragging the mouse.

```
    public class SwingPaintDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300,300);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private int x, y, x2, y2;

    public MyPanel() {

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                x2 = e.getX();
                y2 = e.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
//        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
        x = x2;
        y = y2;
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1) If I call `super.paintComponent(g)` nothing is drawn, why is that?

2) In the code above, I reset `x, y` to be equal to `x2, y2` in `paintComponenet()`, but I originally tried to reset them within `mouseDragged` like so:

```
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();
            repaint();
            x = x2;
            y = y2;
        }
```

However, this did not create lines, only a series of points. To my understanding, these two approaches should have been equivalent. How are they different?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second one is because the entire component is repainted each time you move the mouse.  A repaint includes a paint of the background color, meaning the previous drawing is erased each time the repaint occurs.  So you just see the last little bit of the drawing.

Comment: I guess I still don't quite follow. `repaint()` is being called in both cases. The only difference between the two, was in the wrong approach, I tried to reset `x, y` in `mouseDragged` vs in `paintComponent`.

Comment: For `repaint()`, read the docs. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint-- `repaint()` is a flag to Swing that a component needs painting, but it doesn't happen immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke the `repaint()` method a request is made to the `RepaintManager`. Then `RepaintManager` will then (potentially) combine multiple `repaint()` requests into once call to the `paint()` method of the component, which in turn will invoke the `paintComponent()` method.

So, by the time the `paintComponent()` method is invoked the statements after the repaint() statement will already have been executed so the x/y values will already have been updated.

You should always invoke `super.paintComponent()` at the start of your method to make sure the background is cleared. If you want to do incremental painting the check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) which explains the two common ways to do this.